# Unable to apply changes on device: DEVICE####. Error is: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I get this issue after my first android build; then, before that, the project run in development in the device and even in an emulator. Also the error happens in the emulator too.

I has been researching about that. Update to the current last versions of NativeScript `tns-android: 5.4.0` `tns-core-modules: 5.4.3` `nativescript-vue: 2.2.2`, also update the firebase plugin `nativescript-plugin-firebase: 9.0.1`. And this doesn’t allows me to continue the project. I am so frustrated in this moment about this issue.

```sh
Unable to apply changes on device: DEVICE####. 
Error is: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined.
```

Using the `--log trace` this is shown

```sh
Will emit event liveSyncError with data { error:
   { Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
at Errors.fail (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:126:28)
    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:136:21)
    at AndroidProjectService.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/android-project-service.js:666:34)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/android-project-service.js:11:65)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
     name: 'Exception',
     message: 'Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1',
     stack: 'Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1\n    at Errors.fail (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:126:28)\n    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:136:21)\n    at AndroidProjectService.<anonymous> (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/android-project-service.js:666:34)\n    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)\n    at rejected (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/android-project-service.js:11:65)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)',
     errorCode: 127,
     suppressCommandHelp: true,
     proxyAuthenticationRequired: false,
     printOnStdout: undefined },
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance for any help, this has totally block the development of the project.

Comment: Changing `next` version to `0.24.1` of `nativescript-dev-webpack` solved it in my app.

Comment: Thank you so much @MehulPrajapati your suggested solution remove that issue; but now the App when start shows a message indicating that the App has stopped and after a few seconds appear `Unable to apply changes on device: DEVICE####. Error is: Socket connection timed out..`. This Happened to you too?

Comment: Yes, After restarting my laptop, It worked for me. You can just logout of session and try again.

Comment: @MehulPrajapati not functioned for me. I think that this issue is related with gradle, and is frustrating because not more info is showed about why the app stop to running. Do you know if there is a way to get more info about this kind of errors. I don't know if the best option is to start a new project, but this project is so advanced in its development to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

this error is expected if you are trying to use nativescript-dev-webpack@next with latest official version of NativeScript CLI (5.4.2) as they are not compatible with one another (preparing for NativeScript 6.0 release).

If you would like to use nativescript-dev-webpack@next you will need to install nativescript@next as well.

Hope this helps!